# Inference pytorch C++ with alexnet and cv::imread image

Tags: c++, opencv, pytorch

I am trying to infer with a C++ application an image classification task using an alexnet pre-trained net.
I have successfully inferred a dog image loading the net with python:

```
alexnet = torchvision.models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
img = Image.open("dog.jpg")
transform = transforms.Compose([
 transforms.Resize(256),                
 transforms.CenterCrop(224),        
 transforms.ToTensor(),                  
 transforms.Normalize(                   
 mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],         
 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]              
 )])
img_t = transform(img)
batch_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0)
alexnet.forward(batch_t)
_, index = torch.max(out, 1)
```

Result `index` is 208, Labrador_retriever, that looks good.
Then I save the net to be loaded from a C++ application

```
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
traced_script_module_alex = torch.jit.trace(alexnet, example)
traced_script_module.save("alexnet.pt")
```

When I  load to C++, I get the wrong result:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("dog.jpg");
cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(224, 224), cv::INTER_CUBIC);

// Convert the image and label to a tensor.
torch::Tensor img_tensor = torch::from_blob(img.data, { 1, img.rows, img.cols, 3 }, torch::kByte);
img_tensor = img_tensor.permute({ 0, 3, 1, 2 }); // convert to CxHxW
img_tensor = img_tensor.to(torch::kFloat);
std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> input;
input.push_back(img_tensor);
torch::jit::script::Module  module = torch::jit::load("alexnet.pt");
at::Tensor output = module.forward(input).toTensor();
std::cout << output.argmax(1) << '\n';
```

the `argmax` is 463, bucket.
I think I am not looking at the same image; what am I missing...?

Comment: where's normalization transform in your C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ code is missing this part of your Python code:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
 transforms.Resize(256),                
 transforms.CenterCrop(224),        
 transforms.ToTensor(),                  
 transforms.Normalize(                   
 mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],         
 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]              
 )])
img_t = transform(img)
```

Comment: Yes, I know... but `transforms` unfortunately works with `torch::data::datasets` data loader only. I want to use raw image data because in the future it will be data from a camera.  I tried `img_tensor = img_tensor.div(255);` and `img_tensor = img_tensor.sub(0.485).div(0.225);` to get `[0..1]` range and normalize but same results.

Comment: @StefanoPiovesan ok, here's a deal. you either train your network with the unmodified RGB images (not recommended), or you convert your images to the format the network was trained on. All these transforms are quite easy to implement in OpenCV, so if you don't have `torch`, you have to do that manually -- basically every transform is one line of OpenCV code, not that difficult to do...

Comment: Shame on me: I saved `traced_script_module` (a previous trained `resnet18` model in the same notebook) instead of` traced_script_module_alex` as `alexnet.pt`. Now it works...!